# running processes in background php

Tags: php, cron

I have few cronjob that summarize data and validate data for my site. Some of them have processes that needs to be run in background.

Example:

```
cronjob1.php execute cronjob2.php using exec
```

This cronjob2.php runs another cronjob3.php using `exec` and cronjob3 needs to be completed then cronjob2 and then cronjob finish.

I currently have an issue where the cronjob1.php takes 2 hours to finish.

is there a better way to run this so it run faster?

Thank You

Comment: what kind of tasks those CRON job are doing? difficult for us to judge if it can run faster

Comment: summarize data and validate so visitor statistics, product statistics - cpa, cpc, # of orders etc...

Comment: some generic advise, try to have a persistent connection to the database, optimize your database by creating some specific index and try to simplify or optimize the logic of your scripts

Comment: i don't use persistent connection, and i have over 100 queries which i have to check index but how?

Comment: I would be you, first make your script write some log file with some timestamps, this way you can know which part of the code is the slowest. When you know which queries are the slowest, you can create some index by analyzing the conditions in the where section. If you have 100 queries the permanent connection should help a bit.

Comment: to add what RageZ said, use the `explain` for every query (if you use mysql)

Comment: @RageZ can you put this as an answer?

Comment: @GilbertKakaz: usually you don't reply to your question, I will answer

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is few things that you can do:

- make sure that your script use permanent connection, this way you won't loose time connecting and disconnecting from the database server.
- implement a logging mechanism, so you can identify which part of the script run slowly, logging the time spent on each database queries would be a good idea
- try to optimize your database as much as possible, you should use explain on slow queries and create the needed indexes.

Answer (score 0):

if cronjob1 have many database operation than create store procedures for that and make indexing on most use table fields

this increase your cronjob performance....